# Hostile work environment

Tags: work-environment, politics

I've worked in an IT company as a developer for the last 8 months. During my first project in this company for first 6 months, I was given no work as my manager thought I was not capable enough. I was moved out of that project to another project.

In this project there were many design issues and my lead did not report it to the manager and used to get them fixed at my desk. Due to these issues, the project was delayed and I was seen as responsible for the delay.

I had asked my lead many a times to get the HTML fixed by the design team, but he did not listen. I was asked to stay at work late while a girl from the design team sat at my computer to fix design issues, but I refused.
This created problems between me and my technical lead.

Later on when he went on leave, I reported this matter to the manager and other seniors and got it resolved. Now he has come back and has started targeting me for small issues and reporting them to higher management. His behaviour was never good with me but now it has become worse. Also I have not been completing office hours (many people in this company do not complete it) and now I fear it will become an issue.

Please suggest to me what I should do in this situation. I do not understand office politics and I do not know how to play. I think I should resign immediately.

Comment: Speculation: by completing office hours, do you maybe mean timesheets? Or do you mean coming in late / leaving early?

Comment: Do you have a HR department, or a senior manager you can report this problem to?

Comment: You should explain to the lead exactly what you just said: "I want to do more projects, and I understand you feel I am not ready but I feel I am. Please give me something to prove I am worth it." From there if they're not willing to put you to work then start looking to leave the company. Thus far it doesn't sound like you made it clear that you want to do more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Please suggest me what to do in this situation... I think I should
>   resign immediately.

I seldom advise people to resign without having a new job to go to.

Quitting without a job waiting can easily lead to a financial situation where you need to take the first job that becomes available, rather than the right job for you. This could lead to yet another case where you feel you need to leave after a short stay. You don't want to look like a job-hopper. It's important to stay on the payroll to avoid this situation.

Instead, **first work hard to find your next job, *then* resign**.

Work hard to find a company that fits your needs, and where you will expect to stay for the long term. Do some research on the company, talk to others (perhaps some who already work there), and ask great questions during your interview(s). Hopefully, this leads to a better decision this time around.

Comment: that is an outstanding answer. What are some questions to ask to avoid a toxic work environment? How can you really assess via a line of questioning?

Comment: also with a lot of new companies being born, sometimes its hard to talk to others who work or have worked there and do enough research like gather reviews and such.